# Substitution in an Array List

Tags: java, arrays

I have to list out 10 unique numbers between 1 and 20, but before storing the numbers, the program should check whether the number is in the list or not. If the number is already in the list, it should generate a new number. Also, the amount of numbers replaced must be counted.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] arrayA = {16, 14, 20, 3, 6, 3, 9, 1, 11, 2};

    System.out.print("List: ");
    for(int w = 0; w < arrayA.length; w++)
    {
        System.out.print(arrayA[w] + " ");
    }
}
```

As you can see, there are two "3"s on the list, I have to output the same list but change one of the "3"s. Plus it has to be counted.

Comment: Your title says "Array List" but your code is using arrays. You're aware that they are not the same thing, I trust.

Comment: No I was not. But now I am.

Answer (score 1):

This is not hard to do, but what do you mean by change one of the threes?

You can add a boolean flag outside of your for loop that can tell if you've encountered a 3 or not and what the index of that 3 is.

Try something like this:

```
boolean changedThree = false;
int threeIndex = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++){
   if(arrayA[i] == 3 && !changedThree){
      arrayA[i] = 4;
      threeIndex = i;
      changedThree = true;
   }
   System.out.println(arrayA[i] + " ");
}
```

I don't know for sure if that captures the information you need, but hopefully can give you a push in the right direction. Let me know if you have questions.

**EDIT**

To avoid any duplicate values, I recommend you create an array list, and add the unique values to it. Then, you can use the `ArrayList.contains()` method to see if a value exists already. So, I would recommend changing your code to this:

```
ArrayList<int> usedCharacters = new ArrayList<int>();
int changedCounter = 0;
Random rand = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++){
   if(!usedCharacters.contains(arrayA[i])){ // If we haven't used this number yet
      usedCharacters.add(arrayA[i]);
   } else{
      // Generate a new number - make sure we aren't creating a duplicate
      int temp = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
      while(usedCharacters.contains(temp)){
         temp = rand.nextInt(20) + 1;
      }
      // Assign new variable, increment counter
      arrayA[i] = temp;
      changedCounter++;
   }
}
```

If you're not familiar with the random.nextInt() method, read t[h](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/random_nextint_inc_exc.htm)is.

Comment: I assume he just don't want duplicates in his array. The 3 is just an example....

Comment: Thanks McAdam331! This definitely gave me a boost.

Comment: @MarkBenabese take a look at my edit. I don't have access to my IDE right now, so some stuff might need to be tweaked slightly but I hope it helps.

Comment: For example, I think you might need to make it an ArrayList of Integers, not ints.

Comment: @MarkBenabese any luck?

Answer (score 0):

so if I understand you correctly you have to save the arrayA, right?
If that is the case, you can just make a new array, targetArray where you can save to numbers to, and then check using a for-loop if you already added it, and if so you can generate a new, random number. 
The result would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arrayA = {16, 14, 20, 3, 6, 3, 9, 1, 11, 2};
    int[] targetArray = new int[10];
    int numbersReplaced = 0;

    System.out.print("List: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < targetArray.length; j++) {
            if (arrayA[i] == targetArray[j]) {
                targetArray[j] = (int)(Math.random() * 100);
                numbersReplaced++;
            } else {
                targetArray[j] = arrayA[i];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Numbers replaced: " + numbersReplaced);
}
```

Hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is the sort of question I prefer to give guidance answers rather than just paste in code.

You could walk the array backward looking at the preceding sublist. If it contain the current number you replace with a new one.

Get the sublist with something like Arrays.asList(array).subList(0, i) and then use .contains().

You logic for finding what number to add depends on lots of stuff, but at it simplest, you might need to walk the array once first to find the "available" numbers--and store them in a new list. Pull a new number from that list each time you need to replace.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments you can make use of Java Set here as well. See the [Set docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html).

Comment: To ensure no number is stored twice (or more) he could use a `Set<int> uniqueNumbers`

Comment: @Wavemaster `Set<Integer>` unless you're using a version of Java from the future where you can put primitives into collections.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion to achieve your result.
This will keep looping until all values are unique

```
private void removeDoubles(int[] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        // iterate over the same list
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            // Now if both indexes are different, but the values are the same, you generate a new random and repeat the process
            if(j != i && arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                // Generate new random
                arr[j] = random.nextInt(20);
                // Repeat
                removeDoubles(arr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```